# Is there a way to remove confidence intervals from qqPlot in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Basically what the title says. I'm using the `qqPlot` function from the `car` package but I don't want the confidence intervals on the graph.

Here's my code:

```
qqPlot(result, dist = "chisq", df = mean(result[,1], na.4m=T), 
       lwd=1, col.lines=carPalette()[1],
       grid=F, id=F, line = "robust"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?car::qqPlot`

> envelope: confidence level for point-wise confidence envelope, or
> ‘FALSE’ for no envelope.